# DataGrid is not show the data instead its show Model Class Name

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

When I bind the data collection to my data grid its not show the data instead of data it show the model class name how many row i have that much of time. I tried the normal WPF Data Grid and Dev Express Data Grid both but anything is not working to me.

XAML:

Using WPF DataGrid

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding EmpDetails}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
```

Using Dev Express DataGrid

```
 <dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding EmpDetails}" AutoPopulateColumns="True" AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew" >
                            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                                <dxg:TableView />
                            </dxg:GridControl.View>
                        </dxg:GridControl>
```

I have 2 record in my collection please find below image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdjQt.jpg

Dev Express DataGrid run time Image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iq9VC.jpg

WPF DataGrid run time Image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMgd8.png

Thanks for your spending time to my question.

Comment: can you 1. post the code of your `EmployeeDetails` class and 2. add an image of the displayed datagrid

Comment: EmployeeDetails is only for the model class. It have some property's. Every column of the table  have each property of the model class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the EmployeeDetails is Observable Collection and All the Columns of the table write as the Property with OnPropertyChange include the Model Class.

EX:

```
private string firstName;
public string FirstName
{
 get {return firstName;}
 set { firstName = value; OnPropertyChange("FirstName");}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the type T in the IEnumerable returned from your "EmpDetails" source property has a *public property* (not a field) for each column that you want to be auto-generated in the DataGrid. Please refer to the following sample code.

**Model:**

```
Public Class EmployeeDetails
  Public Property ColumnA As String
  Public Property ColumnB As String
End Class
```

**View Model:**

```
Public Class ViewModel
Public Sub New()
    EmpDetails = New List(Of EmployeeDetails)
    EmpDetails.Add(New EmployeeDetails With {.ColumnA = "A1", .ColumnB = "B1"})
    EmpDetails.Add(New EmployeeDetails With {.ColumnA = "A2", .ColumnB = "B2"})
End Sub

Public Property EmpDetails As ObservableCollection(Of EmployeeDetails)

End Class
```

**View:**

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding EmpDetails}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
</Grid>
```

[MainWindow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGqGa.png)

Comment: No mm8, My Collection is not a IEnumerable. Its a EmployeeDetails Class. Can you see my 1st Image

Comment: An ObservableCollection<EmployeeDetails> is an IEnumerable<EmployeeDetails> (the ObservableCollection<T> class implements the IEnumerable<T> interface)...so you should make sure that your EmployeeDetails has a public property per column you want to be auto-generated in the DataGrid.

Comment: Yes, All are Public Properties only

Comment: Apparently not...please refer to the sample code I provided. It clearly works as the image demonstrates. You should compare your code with this. Please also post the implementation of your EmployeeDetails class if you need any furher help.